# spin up docker-compose using python subprocess fails

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, all I want to do is spin it up using a python script.
The command runs perfectly fine in the terminal, but when it comes to the python script, it fails on an error

```bash
{FileNotFoundError}[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-compose'
```

this is my script

```py
compose_path = "path/to/compose"
cmd = ["docker-compose", "-f", "docker-compose.yml", "up", "-d"]
subprocess.call(cmd, cwd=compose_path)
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `run` instead of `call` ?

Comment: You don't need the hyphen anymore. compose is a built in subcommand of Docker itself. The error is saying that the command you're using doesn't exist